# Initializing field that has getter and setter?

Tags: android, class, kotlin, getter-setter

I created a class which has an example field in Kotlin

```
class SomeClass {
    var smth: String = "Initial value"
            get() = "Here it is"
            set(value) {
                field = "it is $value"
            }
}
```

When I create an object of the class and call the `smth` field, it will call the `get()` property anyway.

```
        val myValue = SomeClass().smth// myValue = "Here it is"
```

So, the question is: why do we have to initialize a field which has getter?

```
 var smth: String // Why this gives error?
        get() = "Here it is"
        set(value) {
            field = "it is $value"
        }
```

It will always return value from `get()` property, doesn't it?

Comment: this is because Kotlin will not generates any backing field when use `get() = ...` without any initialized value. e.g: `val smth: String get() = "Here it is"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just think it is because the compiler is not smart enough to infer that it is not null.

Actually a very similar code presented from the official doc here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

```
var stringRepresentation: String
    get() = this.toString()
    set(value) {
        setDataFromString(value) // parses the string and assigns values to other properties
    }
```

Apparently this code won't compile either unless  a constructor like

```
constructor(stringRepresentation: String) {
    this.stringRepresentation = stringRepresentation
}
```

is added.

Answer (score 3):

You have backing field `field` in setter, so we should initialize, See this [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)